# Decay rate of the coefficients in the Legendre series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, asymptotics, legendre-polynomials

Let $u$ be a function in $L^2_{\nu}([0,\pi])$ where $\nu=2\sin(x)$

Let $\hat{u}_n$ denote the truncated Legendre series expansion of $u$ defined by 
            \begin{equation*}
    \hat{u}_n:= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{2i+1}{2}\langle {u}, {P_i}\rangle P_i(\cos(x)),
   \end{equation*}
where $$\langle {u}, {P_i}\rangle = \int_0^\pi u(x)*P_i(\cos(x))d\nu(x) = \int_0^\pi u(x)*P_i(\cos(x))*(2\sin(x))d(x).$$

I'm interested in the the error approximating $u$ with $\hat{u}_n$, i.e. the difference $u-\hat{u}_n$. Since $u$ can be expanded as an infinite series of Legendre polynomials difference is simply the tail

\begin{equation}
\|u-\hat{u}_n\| = \left\|\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{2i+1}{2}\langle {u}, {P_i}\rangle P_i(\cos(x)) \right\|
\end{equation}

Since I'm interested in large $n$ I've tried using Stieltje's Theorem for the bound
\begin{equation}\label{Stieltjes}
|P_n(\cos(x))\leq \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi n \sin(x)}}, \quad 0<x<\pi, n=1, 2, \ldots. 
\end{equation}

Using this bound in the error term I get

\begin{equation}
\|u-\hat{u}_n\|\leq C*\|u\| \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
\end{equation}

where $C$ is a constant. So this isn't very useful because the sum diverges.

I know there are recent results on this topic in Wang, H. and Xiang, S., 2012. *On the convergence rates of Legendre approximation*, but their results assume some kind of differentiability.

Can a finer error rate be achieved for a general function $u$ in $L^2_{\nu}([0,\pi])$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Legendre polynomials are an orthonormal basis  $(e_n)$, for any $(c_n)\in \ell^2$, $\sum_n c_n e_n\in L^2_\nu$, so there is no uniform decay. If you assume that $u\in C^\infty$ there is one, from the formula for $P_n'$

Comment: @reuns, Are you referring to using integration by parts if $u$ is in $C^{\infty}$?